# alternative to getText() function app script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-docs

After selecting the text from google doc using getSelection() I am trying to get the selected text
but it is not returning the same text

ex:-***Below is sample text on a google-doc***

which is colored blue and bold
but it is returning me a plain text with all its attributes set as NULL

Please tell me how to fix this

is there any alternative to getText() function

Below is my code if its type is TEXT

```
if (type == DocumentApp.ElementType.TEXT) {
        var txt=element.copy();
        Logger.log(txt);
        var text = body.editAsText();
        text.appendText(txt.getText());
        // var par = body.appendParagraph(txt.getText());
        Logger.log("i am text");
        Logger.log(txt.getText());
        Logger.log(text.getParent());
        text.getAttributes();
        text.getBackgroundColor();
        Logger.log(text.getBackgroundColor());
        Logger.log(text.getAttributes());
      }
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately I cannot understand about your question. What is `ex:-Below is sample text on a google-doc`? And, in order to correctly understand about your question, can you provide the sample input and output situation you expect as the images?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are asking for the attributes of the document `Body` cast as a `Text` element.

`var text = body.editAsText();`

Not the current `selection` like:

`var selection = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getSelection();`

Also, you may need to recursively iterate over the [RangeElements](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range#getRangeElements()) (and possibly it's children) in the selection ([Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/range)).

You can then check the [Element](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/element) attributes.

```
const element = rangeElement.getElement();
const attributes = element.getAttributes();
```

This will *only* return attributes that are applied to the *entire* element.

---

If you need attributes that are contained within an element, you will need to iterate again into the element's children. If for example you want the Text Element's of a [Paragraph](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph) you can use the Paragraph [GetChild()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#getChild(Integer)) method.

[Text](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text) Elements also have a function for retrieving the indices of what are called "text runs" or "formatting runs" in Document files. You can get these using the [getTextAttributeIndices()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#getTextAttributeIndices()) function of a Text element.

You can't cast the whole Range (body in your example) as a [Text](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text) element since it won't have the styling applied to the whole selection it will return `null` as the result.

Comment: Thanks for your response but I want selected text to appear with already applied attributes but it is returning me a plain text and also it type is TEXT. When i select a paragraph it works fine because it identifies it as PARAGRAPH. I hope you will understand.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You want to **get** the attributes of a Text element? 
Are you sure the selection is **actually** a Text element OR are you **casting it to be** a Text element? (with editAsText() ). 

If you are sure that the selection is really a Text element, I answered how to read the attributes of Text elements in my answer.  see `getTextAttributeIndices()`

Comment: @KumarKrishna If you are talking about the [getText()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/text#gettext) function, it returns a string of plain text. That's what it's supposed to do.

Comment: Can you please tell how to render a list inside a table using selection and its type because it does not show the list inside the table when i select and run my function

Comment: You have to post a new question. More specific and show where you are having trouble. That's a nontrivial question to answer.